# Books on Faraday, Maxwell

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, history, maxwell-equations, induction

Can you recommend a/some good book(s) on [Faraday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Faraday) for the lay person?  In particular, in relation to his 'Experimental Researches in Electricity'.

Also, any books explaining how Maxwell explained Faraday's work in mathematical terms.

Comment: Also interested in history, so any books explaining discoveries leading up to Faraday/Maxwell would be welcomed.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Michael Faraday* by L. Pearce Williams.  Lots of biographical information but also detailed explications of his work referencing his published papers and diary.  No math though, since Faraday wasn't a mathematician, **but he was a great experimentalist!**

Comment: Loved that book.  Anything similar on Tesla?